# How to calculate the error terms in mixed ANOVA?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, two-way

I recently came across this question and just couldn’t figure it out.
I have to derive a ANOVA table from the following data:

|  | B1 | B2 | B3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A1** | 35 | 32 | 29 |
| **A2** | 29 | 28 | 27 |

A is a between-participants IV with 2 levels. B is a within-participants IV with 3 levels. Each cell represents the mean of 10 observations. SSTotal is 1520 and no other information (SD, subjects mean...) is available.

I am given a table as following:

|  | SS | df | MS | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | ? | ? | ? | ? |
| **B** | ? | ? | ? | ? |
| **AB** | ? | ? | ? | ? |
| **A-Residual** | ? | ? | ? | ? |
| **B-Residual** | ? | ? | ? | ? |
| **AB-Residual** | ? | ? | ? | ? |
| **Total** | 1520 | 59 |  |  |

For the non-residual parts I’m fine and have come to these results:

|  | SS | df | MS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | 240 | 1 | 240 |
| **B** | 160 | 2 | 80 |
| **AB** | 40 | 2 | 80 |

Given SST=1520, I know the total residual must be 1520-440=1080. I also know the degree of freedom of A-Residual = subjects - A levels = 18, and since this is a mixed design AB Residual can be identical to B Residual with a degree of freedom = 36. But how do I partition the total error (1080) to these two parts (A & B)?

Thanks in advance for your helping!